# How to anchor to target element inside HTML details

Tags: html, anchor

When the summary element is closed, it just doesn't scroll to the top. Is there any way of making it auto-expand or something?

### Here is an example of what I mean:

```html
<details>
  <summary>Header</summary>
  <div id=anchored>
  Should anchor here.
  </div>
</details><br style="font-size:100vh;">
<a href="#anchored">To Header</a>
```

Comment: Can you anchor the details element instead? The anchor is not always visible, so I guess that would be the easiest way.

Comment: @LambdaNinja, I need it to anchor to a particular div inside the anchor in my real example.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, on my version of Firefox and Chrome, it only scrolls when I open the details element.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 ahh yes, here too - please mention this. Like: "When `details` is closed and by clicking the link - I'd like to open `details` and scroll-to the anchor reference (`div`)

Comment: It appears details elements are automatically expanded now when navigating to an anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I see it could be achieved is by **using JS**

- On an anchor element click, find it's target DIV,
- than find a `.closest()` `details` and click it's `summary` element.
- Do all the above only if *targetDIV* is not visible (*details is closed*).

```js
$("[href^='#']").on("click", function() {
  var $targetDIV = $(this.getAttribute("href"));
  if ($targetDIV.is(":hidden")) {
    $targetDIV.closest("details").prop("open", true);
  }
});
```

```html
Don't open summary.<br>
Scroll to the bottom of page and click the link.<br>
Summary should open and the page scroll.

<details>
  <summary>Header</summary>
  <div id=anchored>Should anchor here.</div>
</details>

<p style="height:100vh;"></p>
<a href="#anchored">To Header</a>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Without jQuery

Using pure JS (ES6) it would look like:

```js
const openDetailsIfAnchorHidden = evt => {
  const targetDIV = document.querySelector(evt.target.getAttribute("href"));
  if ( !! targetDIV.offsetHeight || targetDIV.getClientRects().length ) return;
  targetDIV.closest("details").open = true;
}


[...document.querySelectorAll("[href^='#']")].forEach( 
   el => el.addEventListener("click", openDetailsIfAnchorHidden )
);
```

```html
Don't open summary.<br>
Scroll to the bottom of page and click the link.<br>
Summary should open and the page scroll.

<details>
  <summary>Header</summary>
  <div id=anchored>Should anchor here.</div>
</details>

<p style="height:100vh;"></p>
<a href="#anchored">To Header</a>
```

Comment: But if it is already open, it is closing the header and not scrolling

Comment: no, in your example, if i open the Header manually, then go down and click the  'Go header", it's not going, it's closing the Header... I suggest to maybe add a check to see if it's already open, then scroll, if not: open then scroll

Comment: @CalvinNunes yeah :) I realized that after your comment. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 fixed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Is there a no jquery version of this?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 No jQuery version added - if it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple details enclosing something.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have ids for each of your details. This will work if you have multiple enclosing each other. A lot of credit to @Roko C. Buljan

```js
const openDetailsIfAnchorHidden = (evt) => {
  const el = evt.target;
  let details = document.querySelector(el.getAttribute("href"));
  if ( !!details.offsetHeight || details.getClientRects().length ) return;
  while (details != null)
  {
      details = details.closest("details:not(#" + details.id +
      ")");
      if (details == null)
        return;
      const summary = details.querySelector("summary");
      details.setAttribute('open', '');
  }
}


[...document.querySelectorAll("[href^='#']")].forEach( 
   el => el.addEventListener("click", openDetailsIfAnchorHidden )
);
```

```html
Don't open summary.<br>
Scroll to the bottom of page and click the link.<br>
Summary should open and the page scroll.

<details id=d1>
  <summary>Header</summary>
  <details id=d2><summary>Header 2</summary><div id=anchored>Should anchor here.</div></details>
</details>

<p style="height:100vh;"></p>
<a href="#anchored">To Header</a>
```