# How to expand details/summary when opening page with anchor inside nested "details"?

Tags: html

I made collapsible html `<ul>` list using `<details>` `<summary>`.

However, if I try to reference to bookmark it does not open automatically. In below example, I would love to call url page with `#Q0A0` to see page automatically open `Q0` node and `Q0A` subnode to make `Q0A0` visible:

e.g.: `list.html#Q0A0`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Details/summary opened with anchor via javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><details id="Q0"><summary>Q0</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><details id="Q0A"><summary>Q0A</summary>
      <ul>
        <li><details id="Q0A0"><summary>Q0A0</summary>Answer to Q0A0</details></li>
        <li><details id="Q0A1"><summary>Q0A1</summary>Answer to Q0A1</details></li>
        <li><details id="Q0A2"><summary>Q0A2</summary>Answer to Q0A2</details></li>
      </ul>
      </details>
    </li>
    <li><details id="Q0B"><summary>Q0B</summary>Answer to Q0B</details></li>
    <li><details id="Q0C"><summary>Q0C</summary>Answer to Q0C</details></li>
  </ul>    
  </details>
</li>
<li><details id="Q1"><summary>Q1</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><details id="Q1A"><summary>Q1A</summary>Answer to Q1A</details></li>
    <li><details id="Q1B"><summary>Q1A</summary>Answer to Q1B</details></li>
    <li><details id="Q1C"><summary>Q1A</summary>Answer to Q1C</details></li>
  </ul>    
  </details>
</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/gwpl/bbe44ba341d6e7253ad5eff2b1a2d061), [codepen](https://codepen.io/gwpl/pen/RdEqjZ)

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48258026/544721

Comment: This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076097/544721 ← how to read anchor from URL

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161906/544721 ← how to handle event of anchor change. (to make it react not only on startup)

Comment: Note to self: similar but slightly different problem with expanding phrases: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38286914/544721

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

also: [gist](https://gist.github.com/gwpl/bbe44ba341d6e7253ad5eff2b1a2d061), [codepen](https://codepen.io/gwpl/pen/RdEqjZ)

```js
function MakeArrayOfAllPrefixes(str){
  //console.log("MakeArrayOfAllPrefixes("+str+")");
  var prefixes = [];
  for (var i=1; i<=str.length; i++){
prefixes.push(str.substr(0,i));
  }
  console.log("MakeArrayOfAllPrefixes("+str+") -> returns [" + prefixes + "]");
  return prefixes;
}

function SetOpenAttrForIdsAndPrefixes(ids, openAttrBool){
  $('details').attr('open',false); // close all others first
  console.log("SetOpenAttrForIds([" +ids+"], "+openAttrBool+")");
  for (idindex in ids) {
var id = ids[idindex];
if (id != ""){
  var prefixes = MakeArrayOfAllPrefixes(id);
  for (prefixidx in prefixes) {
    var prefix = prefixes[prefixidx];
    if(openAttrBool==true) { operationstr="Opening"; } else { operationstr="Closing"};
    console.log(operationstr+" <details id='#"+prefix+"'> with $('#"+prefix+").attr('open',"+openAttrBool+");");
    $('#'+prefix).attr('open',openAttrBool);
  }
}
  }
}

function SetOpenAttrForIdsAndPrefixesFromLocationHash(){
  var hashes = $(location).attr('hash').split('#'); 
  SetOpenAttrForIdsAndPrefixes(hashes, true); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  SetOpenAttrForIdsAndPrefixesFromLocationHash();

  if ("onhashchange" in window) {// does the browser support the hashchange event?
  window.onhashchange = function () {
     SetOpenAttrForIdsAndPrefixesFromLocationHash();
  }
  }
});
```

```html
  
<p>
Opens details/summeries, all parths, using prefixes. Supports multiple anchors in url, example:
</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#Q0A0#Q1A">#Q0A0#Q1A</a>,</li>
  <li><a href="#Q0B#Q0C#Q1B#Q1C">#Q0B#Q0C#Q1A#Q1C</a>.</li>
</ul>

<p>
references:
<a href="https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/explaining-the-details-and-summary-elements--cms-21999">1</a>,
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/48258026/544721">2</a>,
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/55308339/544721">3</a>,
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552944/544721">4</a>,
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161906/544721">5</a>.
</p>
  
<ul>
<li><details id="Q0"><summary>Q0</summary>
  <ul>
<li><details id="Q0A"><summary>Q0A</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><details id="Q0A0"><summary>Q0A0</summary><a href="#Q0A0">Answer to Q0A0</a></details></li>
    <li><details id="Q0A1"><summary>Q0A1</summary><a href="#Q0A1">Answer to Q0A1</a></details></li>
    <li><details id="Q0A2"><summary>Q0A2</summary><a href="#Q0A2">Answer to Q0A2</a></details></li>
  </ul>
  </details>
</li>
<li><details id="Q0B"><summary>Q0B</summary><a href="#Q0B">Answer to Q0B</a></details></li>
<li><details id="Q0C"><summary>Q0C</summary><a href="#Q0C">Answer to Q0C</a></details></li>
  </ul>    
  </details>
</li>
<li><details id="Q1"><summary>Q1</summary>
  <ul>
<li><details id="Q1A"><summary>Q1A</summary><a href="#Q1A">Answer to Q1A</a></details></li>
<li><details id="Q1B"><summary>Q1B</summary><a href="#Q1B">Answer to Q1B</a></details></li>
<li><details id="Q1C"><summary>Q1C</summary><a href="#Q1C">Answer to Q1C</a></details></li>
  </ul>    
  </details>
</li>
</ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. Credits to [vokoscreen](http://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html) for good job at screencasting and ezgif.com for good job at [optimizing gif](https://ezgif.com/resize/ezgif-5-4047548d3322.gif) to fit 2MiB imgur stackoverflow limit.

Comment: After fact I noticed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37033774/544721 similar answer. But without nesting.

Comment: Here codebase without JQuery for similar thing so may be base if someone wants to rewrite to not use JQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100800/544721